# property of modular forms

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

[image]f is holomorphic at the cusps if $$(c\tau+d)^kf(\tau)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_ne^{2\pi i\frac{n}{h}\frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d}},$$ where $a,b,c,d$ are coefficients of a congruence subgroup. Is this equivalent to saying that $$(f|_kM)(\tau)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_ne^{2\pi i\tau n/h}?$$ I think this follows if one substitutes $\tau$ by $M^{-1}\tau.$

I do not understand from which property the  following definition  comes  $$(f|_{k}\gamma)(\tau)=c_n\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{2\pi i \tau n/h} $$  for $\gamma \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z}).$

Answer (score 2):

There is some considerable confusion here. We say that $f$ is holomorphic at a cusp represented by $\frac{a}{c}$ if for any $\gamma = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in \textrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $\gamma(\infty) = \frac{a}{c}$ the function
$$(f\mid_k \gamma)(\tau) = (c\tau + d)^{-k}f(\gamma \tau)$$
is holomorphic at $\infty$.
Holomorphicity at all of the cusps amounts to the statement that $(f\mid_k \gamma)(\tau)$ is holomorphic at infinity for all $\gamma \in \textrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

You seem to think that you can conclude the holomorphicity of $f$ at an arbitrary cusp from the holomorphicity of $f$ at $\infty$.This is true if $f$ is modular on all of $\textrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, since in this case there is only one cusp, but for a given congruence subgroup there may be more than one cusp and holomorphicity at a given cusp doesn't imply holomorphicity at the other cusps.

Comment: Also it is worth mentionning that for a congruence subgroup $f|_k \gamma$ is periodic and has Fourier series, holomorphic means the negative terms vanish, equivalently $f|_k \gamma$ is bounded  at $i\infty$. When it vanishes to find the order of its zero we need to find the smallest translation $z\to z+m$ which is in $\gamma^{-1}\Gamma \gamma$, then $f|_k \gamma\in M_k(\Gamma)$ has a zero of order $\ge l$ at $\Gamma \gamma(i\infty)\in \Gamma \setminus \mathbb{H}^*$ iff $f|_k \gamma(z)=O(e^{2i\pi ml z})$